# Connection Per Request with ADO.net , yes or no?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, database-connection, connection-pooling

Is it ok to open a `IDbConnection` to a database and use it during all called methods in the current request and then allow a DI container to dispose it in `Application_EndRequest`, just like "Context Per Request" pattern that is used with O/RMs like Entity Framework?

Or should I open and close a connection in each method?

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239977/ado-net-best-practice-single-vs-multiple-connections-when-making-asynchronous

Comment: @FelipeOriani : thanks for the link , so the transaction is not applicable with single connection

Answer (score 0):

Better is you create a connection in request and dispose it when page unload event is triggered. In that way you will be disposing off not required resources.

You must follow this way:-

- Override Page_PreInit: initialize connection, open it and start new transaction.
- Override Page_Load: read database and create collections.
- Override Page_Unload: commit/rollback transaction, close connection.
- Override Dispose: implement IDisposable and dispose base objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know the **WebDbConnector** library can help. It will help your web application to create and maintain a connection to the database per request using Ado.Net(SqlConnection), Linq To Sql(DataContext) and Entity Framework(ObjectContext and DbContext).

For Example:

```
// The first parameter of SqlWebDbConnector is connection string
// or connection string name(in Web.config)
var context = new WebDbConnectorContext<SqlConnection>(
    new SqlWebDbConnector("Test", true));
var sqlContext = context.GetCurrentContext();
// TODO: write your own code
```

Then you can implement closing and releasing all resources from inheriting **WebDbConnectorHttpApplication**.

I hope this can help you.

More information at https://github.com/congdongdotnet/WebDbConnector.